# Display all the data in one entry

Tags: templating, entries

How can I display all entries in one page? I have a jobs Channel and inside of it there are 5 entries:

```
Title | Company  | Email
-------------------------
title1  company1   email1
title2  company2   email2
title3  company3   email3
title4  company4   email4
title5  company5   email5
```

I want it to be display in one page

Comment: Are title 1, 2, 3 etc fields or entirely new entries?

Comment: Lance, do you have the entries already setup and just need templating advice? If so, answering Justin's question will help. Or are you wanting help setting the entries up as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [craft.entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries):

```
{% for job in craft.entries.section('jobs') %}
  <div>
    Title: {{ job.title }}<br>
    Company: {{ job.company }}<br>
    Email: <a href="mailto:{{ job.email }}">{{ job.email }}</a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @lanceadriannedelacruz, please consider accepting Jordan's answer if it solved your problem.